# In lieu of write access, can a user be referred to a site with title and tags in the URL?

Tags: support, url-syntax

For an app I'm working on, I'd like to refer users to Stack Overflow instead of providing an "Ask a Question" interface. Users will enter their question and I'll be using the `similar` API to suggest existing questions, but if they want to ask their question, I want to refer them to Stack Overflow with the question title (and a relevant tag) pre-filled. I know it's possible to pass the title like this:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=supdawg`

However, with `tagnames`, it doesn't seem to work the same way. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tags` URL parameter accepts a space-delimited set of tags to prefill in the form. As an example, check the link in the last question of the [Data Explorer FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) which has a URL like:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=data-explorer
```